# How can get all non-static members of a type?

Tags: reflection, d

`__traits(allMembers, T)` returns both instance and static members. How can I filter out the static members? I'd like this to work for both fields and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can do this. D's introspection power is immense, in your case [Filter](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_meta.html#.Filter) from `std.meta` is your friend ;-)

```d
struct Lion
{
    static maxSpeed = 100;
    string name;
    bool isDangerous()
    {
        return true;
    }
    static bool isAlive(uint meat)
    {
        return meat > 100;
    }
}

template FilterMembers(alias T, bool filterStatic = true)
{
    import std.meta : Filter;
    template filter(string member)
    {
        enum memberStr = T.stringof ~ "." ~ member;
        enum isStatic = __traits(isStaticFunction, mixin(memberStr)) ||
                        __traits(compiles, mixin("{auto b = " ~ memberStr ~ ";}"));
        enum filter = filterStatic ^ isStatic;
    }
    enum FilterMembers = Filter!(filter, __traits(allMembers, T));
}


unittest
{
    import std.meta : AliasSeq;
    assert(FilterMembers!Lion == AliasSeq!("name", "isDangerous"));
    assert(FilterMembers!(Lion, false) == AliasSeq!("maxSpeed", "isAlive"));
}

// or using the old-school main
version(unittest) {} else
void main()
{
    import std.stdio;
    foreach (member; FilterMembers!Lion)
        writeln(member);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle a function with arguments, but that can be handled with `__traits(isStaticFunction)`.

Comment: Oh thanks - I updated it, just in case someone else bumps into this ;-)

Comment: Thanks! I also just discovered [witchcraft](http://code.dlang.org/packages/witchcraft) which looks like a good library solution for this and more.

Comment: Yes it looks nice, but be aware that "Every class[/struct] that needs reflective capabilities must mixin Witchcraft".

Comment: @greenify In essence, this looks good, but the way that you're checking for static member variables will run into problems if you ever have a member variable whose type is non-copyable. To handle that, what you want to do instead is something like `__traits(compiles, mixin(memberStr ~ ".offsetof")`, since only member variables will have an offset. Also, you need to do something to handle the `this` member (which I've seen pop up with structs that are declared locally), since `T.this` would not compile. So, while this will work in general as-is, it won't work in some corner cases.

Comment: @JonathanMDavis thanks a lot for clarification! - I am still learning too ;-)

Comment: Turns out witchcraft is for runtime, not compile time reflection. It looks like a nice library but I may end up needing this after all.