# Check if class member is static

Tags: templates, d, traits

I have code like this and I want to check in my template (using a static if), if `C.foo` and `C.bar` are static or not:

```d
class C {
    int foo;
    static int bar;
}
```

I tried these traits already but they don't seem to change for static members:

```d
pragma(msg, __traits(hasMember, C, "foo")); // -> true
pragma(msg, __traits(hasMember, C.init, "foo")); // -> true
pragma(msg, __traits(hasMember, C, "bar")); // -> true
pragma(msg, __traits(hasMember, C.init, "bar")); // -> true
```

This hack which actually works for structs doesn't work for classes either:

```d
pragma(msg, __traits(compiles, { enum tmp = __traits(getMember, C, "foo"); })); // -> false
pragma(msg, __traits(compiles, { enum tmp = __traits(getMember, C.init, "foo"); })); // -> false
pragma(msg, __traits(compiles, { enum tmp = __traits(getMember, C, "bar"); })); // -> false
pragma(msg, __traits(compiles, { enum tmp = __traits(getMember, C.init, "bar"); })); // -> false
```

Comment: Also see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38813868/how-can-get-all-non-static-members-of-a-type?s=8%7C0.0000)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is that static member variables do not have an `offsetof` property. So, you can do something like

```d
template isStaticMember(T, string memberName)
    if(__traits(hasMember, T, memberName))
{
    mixin("alias member = " ~ T.stringof ~ "." ~ memberName ~ ";");
    enum isStaticMember = !__traits(compiles, member.offsetof);
}

class C
{
    int foo;
    static int bar;
}

void main()
{
    static assert(!isStaticMember!(C, "foo"));
    static assert(isStaticMember!(C, "bar"));
}
```

There probably should be something in std.traits for this, but there isn't yet.

Comment: For methods (which are also considered members) you can check `__traits(isStaticFunction)`.